# Information: Cannot find parent 'tsconfig.json' in WebStorm 2018.2.5

Tags: typescript, webstorm

I tried the solution to add `--project "./tsconfig.json"`, but then I have this error:

> Script info with non-dynamic relative file name can only be open script info Error: Debug Failure.

Answer (score 1):

"Cannot find parent tsconfig.json" message is shown if the current file is not included in any `tsconfig.json` file; WebStorm searches for the `tsconfig.json` file starting in the directory file is located in and continuing up the parent directory chain, just like TypeScript compiler does.

Problems normalizing paths when specifying `-p` in Service options is tracked as [WEB-32346](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-32346), please follow it for updates